# how to split a vector and keep the begining and end of each split

Tags: r

Lets assume I have a vector like below

```
x <- 1:100
```

I want to split it into a sequence of 20 and I can use the following to do it

```
seq(1,100, by=20)
#[1]  1 21 41 61 81
```

what I want is to print each begining and end of split

```
for (i in seq(1,length(x), by=20)){
 print(x[i])
}
```

however, it does not give me the answer I need, I need to have this

```
1:20
21:40
41:60
61:80
81:100
```

Is there a way to do it ?

Answer (score 2):

```
paste(seq(1,100, by=20), seq(20, 100, 20), sep = ':')
#[1] "1:20"   "21:40"  "41:60"  "61:80"  "81:100"
```

Comment: one little problem, when my end point is 100, then this works fine but if my end point is 101 then it fails, look at here paste(seq(1,101, by=20), seq(20, 101, 20), sep = ':')